# Mongoose select fields to return from findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose in Nodejs you can return some fields using find.
eg.

```
User.findOne({_id:'132324'}, {first_name:1, last_name:1}).exec...
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to return certain fields using findOneAndUpdate.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:'132324'}, {$set : {..bla bla}}, {first_name:1, last_name:1}).exec....
```

Has anyone achieved this before?
I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: That's not what i'm asking at all. I dont care to retrieve the new data or old data using  {new:true}. Please read the question

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the [manual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), the `options` argument needs a `"fields"` key in it since there are other details such as `"upsert"` and `"new"` where this applies. In your case you **also** want the `"new"` option:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": "132324" },
  { "$set": { "hair_color": "yellow" } },
  {
   "fields": { "first_name":1, "last_name": 1 },
   "new": true 
  }
).exec(...)
```

Alternately you may use [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

```
User.select({ "first_name": 1, "last_name": 1 }).findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": "132324" },
  { "$set": { "hair_color": "yellow" } },
  { "new": true }
).exec(...)
```

Noting that without `"new": true` the document returned is in the state **before** the modification of the update was processed. Some times this is what you mean, but most of the time you really want the modified document.

Answer (score 13):

It seems the syntax for `findByIdAndUpdate` has changed a little.

Its takes the form of `Model.findByIdAndUpdate(query, update, options, (optional callback))`

According to the docs, to specify which fields are returned you have to specify them in the *options* parameter. so, using the above example it would be:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {id},  //query
  { $set: { "fieldToBeChanged": "update" } },  //update
  {new:true, select: "fieldIWant anotherFieldIWant"}, //options
})
```

The `new:true` options is not necessary. If omitted mongoose defaults to returning the document before the updates were applied. Set to true and it will return the document after the updates have been made.

Comment: Select can be as object

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {id},  //query
  { $set: { "fieldToBeChanged": "update" } },  //update
  {new:true, select: {_id: 0} }, })

```

Answer (score 3):

We can exclude any field while using mongoose update function **findByIdAndUpdate** with the help of select function,please have a look at the following code it will exclude password and __v from the Update response

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.userData.UserId },req.body,{new: true}).select({Password: 0, __v: 0 })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:'132324'}, {update: '1235'}, {new: true}).select({ _id: 0 })
```

The [`select()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) will exclude the `_id` field from the result.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDb version 3.2+

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id": "132324" },
  { "$set": { "hair_color": "yellow" } },
  {
   "projected": { "first_name":1, "last_name": 1 },
   "returnNewDocument": true 
  }
)...
```

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB version: 4.0.2, mongoose version: 5.13.7:

```
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id:'132324'},{$set: 
{"first_name":"user","last_name":"one"}}, 
{new:true,select:{first_name:1, last_name:1}},(err,data)=>{}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score -4):

Use option {new: true} in findOneAndUpdate (default: false)

Comment: The OP was asking how to exclude certain fields from the returned model.