# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() with select option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the documentation, it must be possible to add the select option to an `findByIdAndUpdate` function in mongoose.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

But, it looks it is not working.

What I want:

I'm building an application with an Facebook API option. So, I save the token which I get from Facebook, but I don't want it to be available in the frontend, so I select select to false on my model.

So in other words the real model looks like:

```
user: {
   name: String,
   //some other fields
   facebook: {
      token: {
         type: String,
         select: false
      },
      profileId: String
      postTo: {
         type: String,
         enum: ['wall', 'page']
      }
      //some other fields
   }
}
```

In my frontend the model look like:

```
user: {
   name: "Test user",
   facebook: {
      profileId: "123456789"
      postTo: "wall"
   }
}
```

The attribute '`postTo`' can be changed, and of course I want it to be saved. So, I used the `findByIdAndUpdate()` function from mongoose to archive that. But, I think, because of the `select: false`, the attribute token is completely removed when I run the this function with the given model above.
How can I run this function without losing data?
I didn't get any errors or something.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.user._id, {$set: updatedUser}, {new: true}).select('facebook.token').exec(function (err, user) {
  log.user("USER", user); //has lost his token
})
```

### Edit:

I have tried the code from this question (was a possible duplicate): [Mongoose select fields to return from findOneAndUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104310/mongoose-select-fields-to-return-from-findoneandupdate) 
But that seems not to work. I have updated my code to something like this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    {_id: req.body.user._id}, 
    {$set: updatedUser}, 
    {
        "fields": {
            "facebook.token":1, 
        },
        "new": true
}).exec(function (err, user) {

})
```

In the question is not going about fields with `select:false` I think, so in my eyes, this is not an duplicate anymore.